# What is the path of 2 different files merged with the option -X renam-threshold=N%

Tags: git, merge

I was working with one file A at a certain commit. On one branch, I renamed this file ( -> I moved it to a newly created repo called Rep) and added a new function. 
On my master branch, I as well added a new function.

I merged these two files using git merge newBranch -X rename-threshold=50%. And it worked well :)

But... I am wondering what do git do to decide what will be the path of the merged file.

my branches

- A (with a new function)
- Rep\newA (with a different new function)

Currently, it merges BUT it creates the Rep in my branch master, whereas it was created in my feature branch. Is it a normal behavior ? Is there any way to choose the path I want to assign to my merged file ?

Regards,
Flo